# Angular route error: "A router outlet has not been instantiated during routes activation"

Tags: angular, routes

I'm getting it for any route. What is this warning and how to fix it?
All the routes working fine BTW.

Comment: Did you add a `router-outlet` in the `app-component`?

Comment: Yes. I think that I know what's the problem:
I have a *ngIf to disable anything until that something is ready, and when I'm saying "anything" it is including also router-outlet.
Since that I don't want to put this *ngIf in all my routes then I'll ignore this warning. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue since the Angular 10.1 update, posting the fix that worked for me for future google searches of others.

Turns out the error had nothing to do with the components on the mentioned route, but with the components navigating to this route.

Multiple components were navigating the router, and I tested this navigation with the following code:

```
spyOn(component.router, 'navigate').and.callThrough();
```

This actually calls the navigation, but that's not necessary.
A mocked resolve of the navigate promise is enough. New version:

```
spyOn(component.router, 'navigate').and.resolveTo();
```

And all the warning disappeared.